# How to do the Quorom operator(Minimum number of words to be present from the query) which is present in sphinxsearch in Lucene?

Tags: search, lucene, sphinx

I have a situation where the indexer has lots of small phrases. The query should be a sentence which after searched for returns those small phrases(from the indexer) present in the query. For this I have used extended mode in sphinxsearch server using quorom operator. 
Is there any similar thing in Lucene??

Answer (score 2):

If you can use Solr, there is DisMax query parser has Minimum 'Should' Match:
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin#mm_.28Minimum_.27Should.27_Match.29

Also check this question [How to match against subsets of a search string in SOLR/lucene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4882481/how-to-match-against-subsets-of-a-search-string-in-solr-lucene) and the answer https://stackoverflow.com/q/4888993/51986