# Phrase match on part of query using solr

Tags: solr

I have following situation:

For query "A B" we have exact match and results scored correctly. But when query is looking like "A B C" results are wrong because Solr doesn't see exact match on "A B". Please help me to configure Solr in proper way to let him find "phrase" match on "A B".

P.S. Following queries are working as expected:

```
A B field:C
"A B" C
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I'm understanding you right, but it sounds like you need to generate [shingles](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.ShingleFilterFactory)  or perhaps [NGrams](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory). In short, shingles are created by grouping words from a sentence and edge NGrams work by generating pieces of words by taking characters from the beginning or the end of a word.

> From Solr Wiki:
>
> - **Ngrams**: Nigerian => "ni", "nig", "nige", "niger", "nigeri",    "nigeria", "nigeria", "nigerian"
> - **Shingles**: For example, the sentence    "please divide this sentence    into shingles" might be tokenized into    shingles "please divide",
>     "divide this", "this sentence", "sentence    into", and "into
>     shingles".

Since you want matches on partial queries, you need to include the relevant filter to the query analyzer.

Comment: Please correct me, if I'm wrong. But that will be big change because Shringles should be added not only for query time, but also to index-time. And also, as I know, that's parallel method with OOB in Solr/edismax to make search on phrases works...

Comment: It sounds to me that you only need to shingle the query and apply a position filter, so that "A B C" becomes <"A B" OR "B C">.
Check out this question, it seems similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4882481/how-to-match-against-subsets-of-a-search-string-in-solr-lucene