# Solr: Exact match for field value

Tags: solr

I am trying to perform an exact match on the stored value (rather than the query value).

My indexed data is something like: "banana republic"

I need the following queries to match:

- shirts from *banana republic*
- *banana republic* items
- stuff *banana republic* and other stuff

These should **not** match:

- banana not republic
- banana is a good fruit
- Chile republic

My scenario is actually simple and easily doable with SQL using a query similar to: `query_string LIKE '%stored_val%'` but I couldn't configure the anlayzers to perform it. I am sure `EdgeNGramFilter` can achieve this, but it would be very expensive to create ngrams that are more than 30 characters long.

**My current implementation is**: In the index analyzer, use `solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory`. In the query analyzer, use `solr.ShingleFilterFactory` (2-4 tokens). Everything looks fine when using the analysis tool. But using the query API, the query gets translated to:

```
rawquerystring: "match_name:"banana republic"",
parsedquery_toString: "match_name:"(banana bananarepublic) republic""
```

which does not match my stored token "bananarepublic"

My analysis chain looks like:

```
  <fieldType name="singletoken" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="../../common-config/mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/> <!-- map accented letters to their ascii equivilants -->
      <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
      <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="[^A-Za-z0-9&amp; ]" replacement=" "/>
      <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="(^\s+|\s+$)" replacement=""/> <!-- join everything in a single token with no spaces -->
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="../../common-config/mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/> <!-- map accented letters to their ascii equivilants -->
      <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
      <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" /> <!-- using all default options from: https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory -->
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
      <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="[^A-Za-z0-9&amp; ]" replacement=" "/>
      <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory" />
      <filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" minShingleSize="2" maxShingleSize="4" outputUnigrams="true" tokenSeparator="" />
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to match against subsets of a search string in SOLR/lucene](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4882481/how-to-match-against-subsets-of-a-search-string-in-solr-lucene)

Comment: Hi @mjalajel did you end up solving your problem? I would love to know the result. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In 4.x and trunk the default value of mm is dictated by the q.op param (q.op=AND => mm=100%; q.op=OR => mm=0%). Keep in mind the default operator is effected by your schema.xml  entry. In older versions of Solr the default value is 100% (all clauses must match)

Did you use this syntax in your query ?

your_domain:8983/solr/select/?q=banana+republic&defType=dismax&q.op=AND&...

OR

your_domain:8983/solr/select/?q=banana+republic&defType=dismax&mm=100%&...

Comment: mm will not work, as he's not planning on matching the terms by themselves - but the sequence of the terms. The SingleFactory (as described in the linked question this is a duplicate of) will solve this. He has also included several example queries, including texts that they should not match. mm will not solve this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to solve this problem without resorting to custom `query Tokenizers`, because the problem resides in the tokenization phase.

lets say that we have this phrase: `banana republic`
and we want to index and query this exact phrase.
what is actually happening is:

**Index Time:** when solr is indexing `banana republic` the tokenizer will split this phrase into two separate phrases so the index will look like this

Phrase: `banana`

Phrase: `republic`

**Query Time:**
at query time you'll also be searching for two separate phrases joined by `OR` operation.

What you actually need is something like this:

**Index**: Phrase: `banana republic` as one token.

**Query**: search for Phrase: `banana republic` as one token.

The best solution is to use is to use a custom phrase tokenizers like this one: https://github.com/lucidworks/auto-phrase-tokenfilter

Comment: How would this work? can you please add an example of the analysis chain?

Comment: Also, auto phrase tokenizer needs a list of phrases, is there a way to do this without a predefined list of phrases?

Comment: Example for the analysis chain:

`<fieldType name="brands_search" class="solr.TextField" >
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <!-- filters -->
     </analyzer>
     <analyzer type="query">
      <!-- tokenizer and filters -->
     </analyzer>
</fieldType>`

And the query parser for sending the search term as "shingles" ( by using this method you wont need to use a predefined list of phrases ):
for example: 
`term=banana republic`
you'll want something like this.
`phrases = (banana) (banana republic) (republic)`